# equation of mixcolumn in the aes field

Tags: aes, rijndael

> $c(y) = (03)y^3 + (01) y^2 + (01) y + (02)$
>
> Let $d = (01)b$ in the AES field $GF(2^8)$.
>
> Provide exact equations for the bits $d_i, 0 \leq i \leq 7$, in terms of the bits $b_i$ of b.

Can some give me an example or hint? I don't know where to start..